# Vedo: Is there a way to add a camera to scenes and see images from perspective?

Tags: python, camera, vedo

I'm using Vedo in Python to visualize some 3D scans of indoor locations.

[image]

I would like to, e.g., add a 'camera' at (0,0,0), look left 90 degrees (or where ever), and see the camera's output.

Can this be done with Vedo? If not, is there a different python programming framework where I can open .obj files and add a camera and view through it programmatically?

Comment: Looks like you can supply a `camera` dict when calling the [`show()`](https://vedo.embl.es/autodocs/content/vedo/dolfin.html#vedo.dolfin.show) command.

Comment: That would be awesome. I'm quite the beginner when it comes to Vedo, any chance you could show me a bit of sample code for this? :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not even a beginner — just looked it up in the fine documentation (after looking at a few example scripts).

Comment: What do you mean by "adding a camera"? Adding an extra independent view of the whole scene, or just modifying the view point of the one you already created? (as martineau suggested you can pass a camera dictionary for that, press C in the viewer for a template code). Feel free to open an issue on the github repo if you need more help.

Comment: @mmusy I mean like in a video game programming environment, add a camera object to a specified position, with a specified orientation and FOV etc, and then view a (2D) image of what that camera object sees. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot the same object in an embedded renderer and control its behaviour via a simple callback function:

```py
from vedo import *

settings.immediateRendering = False  # can be faster for multi-renderers

# (0,0) is the bottom-left corner of the window, (1,1) the top-right
# the order in the list defines the priority when overlapping
custom_shape = [
        dict(bottomleft=(0.00,0.00), topright=(1.00,1.00), bg='wheat', bg2='w' ),# ren0
        dict(bottomleft=(0.01,0.01), topright=(0.15,0.30), bg='blue3', bg2='lb'),# ren1
]

plt = Plotter(shape=custom_shape, size=(1600,800), sharecam=False)

s = ParametricShape(0) # whatever object to be shown
plt.show(s, 'Renderer0', at=0)
plt.show(s, 'Renderer1', at=1)

def update(event):
    cam = plt.renderers[1].GetActiveCamera() # vtkCamera of renderer1
    cam.Azimuth(1) # add one degree in azimuth

plt.addCallback("Interaction", update)

interactive()
```

[image]

Check out a related example [here](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo/blob/master/examples/basic/multirenderers.py).
Check out the `vtkCamera` object methods [here](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCamera.html).

Answer (score 3):

I usually use schema:

```
...
plt = Plotter(bg='bb', interactive=False)
camera = plt.camera
plt.show(actors, axes=4, viewup='y')
for i in range(360):
   camera.Azimuth(1)  
   camera.Roll(-1)
   plt.render()
...
plt.interactive().close()
```

Good Luck